# Sharepoint like functionality to connect to office apps

Tags: php

Is there a way to connect to office applications like Sharepoint does in a custom PHP web app?

Answer (score 1):

Although it might not be possible to support every Sharepoint feature, I think it should be possible to support the basics. Even the basics will take a bit of work though, and involve working with a PHP WebDAV library, IE-only ActiveX controls, and perhaps modifying the user's registry.

[This site](http://www.webdavsystem.com/server/documentation/ms_office_read_only) has some information on how you need to set-up WebDAV so that Office applications can open a file over WebDAV in read/write mode.  Also read up on the [OpenDocuments Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms454230.aspx), and the Registry key it uses.

Using this information you can probably make a Office-compatible WebDAV server using a PHP WebDAV library like [SabreDAV](http://sabre.io/).  The SabreDAV website mentions Open Office compatibility but not Office compatibility so you might have some patching to do.